# NameResolutionFailure vs ConnectFailure issue

Tags: xamarin, dns, httpclient

So a rather peculiar issue, but a pretty bad one nonetheless. When a user enters our app with no internet at all, we get back a `NameResolutionFailure` as the error message for trying to make a API call via `HttpClient`. Okay, that's fine. The issue though is, when the user then connects to internet, goes back to app, and attempts to make another API call, we get the same error message. It appears that some kind of DNS caching is happening?

On the flip side, if a user HAS internet access while in app, then loses it, when we try to make an API call we get a `ConnectFailure(Network is unreachable)` error from the API call. And as soon as the user connects to the internet, they can make API calls instantenously.

The issue I'm trying to figure out is, A) What's the difference between `NameResolutionFailure` and `ConnectFailure` ? and B) Is there anything we can do in app to force it to completely retry the API call without using any cache? It's not obvious to me if the DNS is being cached or not, but we have a hinting feeling that's what's happening.

Here's part of the code (if you need more let me know, I figured this is the only code needed)

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
   client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MaximumWebRequestTime);    
   HttpResponseMessage response = null;
   try
   {
      response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had this issue on iOS too and fixed it by setting the DNS refresh timeout:

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 0;`

It's a temporary fix, but works for now.
Haven't tested it on Android yet. Will do that too shortly.

Edit: Android tested successfully.

Comment: Where did you put that line of code? I'm getting a `The type or namespace name 'ServicePointManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net'`

Comment: Wow looks legit. I put it in AppDelegate, since I can't access .Net stuff in XF. And... it worked! At least from the first try. Going to test more, but thanks buddy!

Comment: Yes, you have to place it in the platform code as from X.F you can't access this.

Answer (score 2):

I just filed a bug on this recently: 
http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45383

This is a regression in Xamarin Android version >= 7.0. You can workaround it by downgrading to Xamarin Android 6.1.2.21. And since it is a regression, it should be a priority and get fixed relatively quickly.

*Note: I am a MS/Xamarin support engineer*

Comment: We're actually seeing this error in iOS. Is it possible there's a larger issue at play that's affecting all platforms?

Comment: It definietely appears to be a bit more of broader issue then just Android (although might be related). I've posted this (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/228788#Comment_228788) in the Xamarin forums, and a couple people are having same issue with Xamarin iOS.

Comment: I just confirmed this issue on iOS and in a Mono console project. New bug reports are being filed. I will provide links when done.

Comment: The Android and iOS bug reports have been marked as a duplicate of the Mono bug report as that is where the bug really is, in Mono >= 4.6.0

Comment: Ugh, so frustrating. As good as Xamarin is, there's definitely some room for improvement. But thanks for your help!