# Getting "Network is unreachable" error on network restore on Xamarin Android App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, httpclient, ihttpclientfactory

I am working on a Android Xamarin App. This app connects to a device through Wi-fi (the device is a Access Point) and while the app is connected to the device, there's no internet connection on the phone.

So when I disconnect from the device AP and connect the phone to another network with internet connection, I try to make HTTP requests to the server and I always get "Network is Unreachable" error, even tho the phone does have connection (tested accessing Chrome). Only works again after I restart the app.

I am using all the good practices I found online regarding HttpClient class (not wrapped in a "using" statement, using only one static HttpClient object instead of creating a new one on each request, etc.)

I implemented IHttpClientFactory to create the HttpClient, but still gets the same error.

My code (simplified):

```
public static class WebRepository
{
private static IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
private static HttpClient _client;

static WebRepository() 
{
    _clientFactory = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    _client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
}

public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
{
    try
    {
        if (Globals.LoggedUser != null)
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", $"{Globals.LoggedUser.Token}");
        HttpResponseMessage message = await _client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await DeserializeResponseMessageAsync<T>(message);
    }
    catch(HttpRequestException e) when(e.InnerException != null && e.InnerException is SocketException && e.Message.Contains("Network is unreachable"))
    {
        _client.CancelPendingRequests();
        _client.Dispose();
        _client = _clientFactory.CreateClient(); //Tried to create a new client in order to "refresh" connection, so in the next Get request it would be a new client, but no luck. Still gets the excepction every time.
        throw e;
    }
    catch(Exception) { throw; }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you request `Access_Natework_state` permission in xamarin.android project? Maybe you can add a check for internet connection before making any request.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT why? Author clearly says, after the network recovers, they keep getting a "Network unreachable" exception. It has nothing to do with checking for the network state before.

Comment: Which HttpClient handler have you selected in your project? I highly recommend using the Android Http Client handler.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I had the ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission in the Manifest. I added the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE now, thanks! About the verification for connection before making any requests, I actually do this. The result is always true, because the phone does have connection, but still gets the error, as Cheesebaron stated. Thanks for permission tip!

Comment: @Cheesebaron I checked and the HttpClient implemantation that currently is selected is "Default" (to be honest I didn't even know about this, still learning about Xamarin). I will switch to Android Handler and make some tests, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @MarceloMenezes If you have any solution, please share it here.

Comment: Unfortunately I had no luck with this issue. I changed the http handler to "Android" as suggested by @Cheesebaron and got a different exception. This time, I got "java.net.UnkonwnHostException: Unable to resolve host "http://myaddress.com": No address associated with hostname." After a network restore is not possible to resolve the host name, apparently.

Comment: I also tried to locally save the Ip adress of the server at startup in order to make the http requests using the Ip address instead, but no luck either. This time I got Socket Exception "java.net.SocketException: socket failed: ENONET (Machine is not on the network)". It still only works when the app is restarted.

Comment: @MarceloMenezes What android version did you use, I find this thread that you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137190/nameresolutionfailure-vs-connectfailure-issue